# loop over array of numbers doesn't square the numbers

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get my code for class to produce the desired results, but what I've got here doesn't do what I'd like.

This is the code that I'm testing:

```
const sampleArray = [
  876, 755, 661, 24532, 758, 450,
  302, 2043, 712, 71, 456, 21, 398,
  339, 882, 9, 179, 535, 940, 12
];

let myFunction = function() {
  let squareNumbers = [];

  for (let counter4 = 0; counter4 < sampleArray.length; counter4++) {
    if (Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2)) {
      squareNumbers.push(sampleArray[counter4])
    }
  }

  console.log(squareNumbers);
}

myFunction();
```

It shows the items in the array, but doesn't square them and I'm at a loss as to why. I've already got a solution a different way, but I feel like there should be something better that I could do

Comment: You're testing against the square in the `if` statement, but you're not pushing the square. Calling `Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2))` is not going to change the value in place. It's also not clear why you are testing that. The only thing that would be false is `0`.

Comment: I thought that by using `Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2)` I'd square the number  pulled from whatever was at `counter4` in which case I'd display that in `squareNumbers.push(sampleArray[counter4])`

Comment: why is the function allowed to reach outside its scope? At the very least make this `function myFunction(array) { ... }` (not as a var, just declare the function) and then invoke it as `myFunction(sampleArray)`. Also, if you're posting code, try to clean up things like `counter4`: just call it `i` and now the code is far more universal. Same for `myFunction`: call it after what it does makes it easier for people to read your code.

Comment: I am testing out the `let myFunction = function()` thing for school since our instructor has a thing for that, I'm not personally liking it much tbh, seems like  unnecessary typing, I also don't see where it was calling outside of its scope except to pull in the global constant `sampleArray`, but I'll make sure to keep an eye on that for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i see what you are after.  How about this:

```
// unchanged
const sampleArray = [876, 755, 661, 24532, 758, 450, 302, 2043, 712, 71, 456, 21, 398, 339, 882, 9, 179, 535, 940, 12];

// unchanged
let squareNumbers = [];

// unchanged
let myFunction = function() {

  // unchanged
  for (let counter4 = 0; counter4 < sampleArray.length; counter4++) {

    // minor change...
    // Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2) squares the number
    // but it only returns the number. 
    // If used within an "if" is returns a form of "true". 
    var mysquare = Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2);

    // this is not required..it's just so you can see "the return"
    console.log("the squre of " + sampleArray[counter4] + " is " + mysquare);

    // To "put it in the array" you must push "the return" onto the array. 
    squareNumbers.push(mysquare)
  }
}

// unchanged
myFunction();
console.log('my squareNumbers:');
console.log(squareNumbers);
```

which produces this:

```
the squre of 876 is 767376
the squre of 876 is 767376
the squre of 755 is 570025
the squre of 661 is 436921 
the squre of 24532 is 601819024 
the squre of 758 is 574564 
the squre of 450 is 202500 
the squre of 302 is 91204
the squre of 2043 is 4173849 
the squre of 712 is 506944
the squre of 71 is 5041 
the squre of 456 is 207936 
the squre of 21 is 441 
the squre of 398 is 158404
the squre of 339 is 114921 
the squre of 882 is 777924 
the squre of 9 is 81 
the squre of 179 is 
the squre of 535 is 
the squre of 940 is 
the squre of 12 is 144
my squareNumbers:
Array(20) [ 767376, 570025, 436921, 601819024, 574564, 202500, 91204, 4173849, 506944, 5041, … ]
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to add a second variable then...I hadn't even considered the need for that...I feel like I need a dunce cap right now

Comment: second variable?  i didn't add anything...take another look.  oh, `mysquare` - yeah, i was trying to clarify the lack of need for the `if` loop..but you can do that _inline_ you don't have to put it in a variable.  that's not the point at all...

Comment: One of the guys in class helped me come up with `squareNumbers.push(sampleArray[counter4] * sampleArray[counter4])` but I thought I could do something  else, which is why I was trying to do it with the for loop

Comment: you can do it with the top for loop, that's not the issue.  the issue, at least what appears to be the main part of it, is that `Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2)` **returns** the value.  Just putting _the value_ in a _test_ within your `if` does not then push it to your array.

Comment: My thought process was that I'd run the `Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2)` which would square that number then put that in `squareNumbers` using the `.push` notation  That's why I used the if statement to begin with, if this, do that...or was I mistaken? I guess my logic is a tad off there :)

Comment: Yes, `Math.pow(sampleArray[counter4], 2)` will _square that number_ but it only _returns_ the number.  If used within an `if` you are essentially just returning a numeric form of "true".  To "_put it in the array_" you must push the return onto the array.  I have not changed your code dramatically.  Please review it line by line, comparing it with your original code.  I think it will be clear.